# Material form fields as foreign objects of an svg form

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, angular8

I am in Angular 8. I have a form template in svg format that has some rectangular boxes that need to be filled. I try to put some input fields in the whitespace inside the boxes by injecting some html inside the svg using the foreignObject element. Regular inputs and textareas work as long as you declare the form fields with an xhtml namespace like so:

```
<foreignObject>
 <xhtml:input placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName"/>
</foreignObject>
```

but when I use material form fields like this :

```
<foreignObject>
  <xhtml:mat-form-field>
    <xhtml:input matInput placeholder="First Name" formControlName="firstName"/>
  </mat-form-field>
</foreignObject>
```

I get template parse errors...

Has anyone ever done anything similar?